# Recognising curse words in long recordings with speech recognition in alien language

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network

What would be the right approach to train a convnet to recognise if a given alien curse word was said in a long recording or not ?

For example, let's say that there are 1000 audio clips in an alien language, each 20 minute long and somewhere in those 20 minutes an alien curse word can occur (`KCUF`), but it is not known where exactly. **It is only known if it occurred or not in a given 20 minute recording.**

Could deep learning speech recognition systems cope with such a task ? Or is it futile task ? If they could cope, what structure should the deep network have ? A simple convnet ? Or a convet + recurrent net on top ?

The reason for asking this : I am wondering if speech recognition could be applied to this Kaggle competition https://www.kaggle.com/c/melbourne-university-seizure-prediction

In particular, I am wondering if this approach would be useful : https://github.com/anlthms/sp-2016

Is there any research done on this topic ? If yes, how can I search for it ? What are the keywords ?

Comment: Only 1000 clips seems little as training data. Given the way data is represented, it will take a Recurrent Net to capture the sound/syllable sequence that form the "curse word" over series of inputs. Convolution will also help, since the word can occur in the beginning or at the end. Alternative approach is to threat the visual representation of the audio clips and train a visual NN to find the imprint of the "curse word". In the end the key will be in the tuning the hyper parameters of the NN and whether the training data is enough, but in general it should be possible.

Comment: Yeah, I had the feeling that 1000 clips are not that much, actually in the Kaggle competition there are about 100 clips where "curse words" might occur and about 1000 clips where they don't. What do you mean visual representation ? Like a spectrogram ?

Comment: yes, exactly like spectrogram.